# How does Haste interact with Boots of Striding and Springing?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, magic-items, movement

So I am currently playing a vine leshy ninja in Pathfinder 1e. I am taking the Acceleration of Form ninja trick and Boots of Striding and Springing.
Important information that you need to know before I ask the question:

- The race’s speed is listed as 20 feet.
- The boots give a +10 bonus to base speed. This is an enhancement bonus.
- *Haste* increases all forms of movement by 30 feet to a maximum of twice the subject’s normal speed using that form of movement. This is an enhancement bonus.

So my question at hand is: how do these interact?

So far me and my gm have come up with three possible answers:

1. *Haste* doubles race move speed, replaces boots as they are both enhancement (Total 40 feet).
2. *Haste* doubles your move speed, replaces boots as both are enhancement (Total 50 feet).
3. *Haste* doubles your move speed - but the enhancement bonus to base speed is different than bonus to total speed and as a result they stack (total 60 feet).

What is the proper interaction between these effects?

Answer (score 12):

## It's #1

The creature's land speed can only benefit from one enhancement bonus. To determine the creature's speed while it's wearing the [*boots of striding and springing*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/a-b/boots-of-striding-and-springing/) and affected by a [*haste*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/haste/) spell…

1. determine the creature's speed using only the effect of the *boots of speed*; then…
2. determine the creature's speed using only the *haste* spell.

After that, the creature uses the higher of those two speeds. This is because both the *boots* and the *haste* spell offer an enhancement bonus, and the two don't combine. (For more on stacking see [here](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/BASICS-ABILITY-SCORES/GLOSSARY/#Stacking).)

Even though the creature is getting an enhancement bonus to all of its modes of movement from the *haste* spell, that enhancement bonus from the *haste* spell applies to the creature's land speed in addition to applying to other speeds. The enhancement bonus from the *haste* spell is not an enhancement bonus to a *new* value named *All of the hasted creature’s modes of movement*.

Comment: +1 though I am not sure what the last paragraph is saying, or if it is necessary in answering the question. You may also want to add that the boots' +5 competence bonus to Athletics still applies even when the enhancement bonus to speed is superseded by _haste_.

Comment: @smbailey Huh. And I thought that last paragraph was the most important part. `:-)` Seriously, I thought the asker might be asking if the two enhancement bonuses stacked because they went to different things (i.e. one's an enhancement bonus to land speed and the other's a different enhancement bonus to all speeds), when, in fact, both enhancement bonuses are just trying (with only the higher succeeding) to modify land speed.